# Using Paperclip with Video upload to get :poster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, video, ruby-on-rails-4, html5-video

In my rails app, users can upload video files that play in the new HTML5 videoplayer. I'm using flowplayer (http://flowplayer.org/) for the player. You can easily add a `:poster` to the video like so:

```
<video poster="img_src_here" controls>
  ..
</video>
```

How can I get a poster (image file) for a user uploaded video?? Is there a way I can capture a screenshot of the first frame of the video??

I would give more code, but after researching this I haven't even found any solutions that can get me started...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ffmpeg` with paperclip to process the video and extract a thumbnail from where-ever you want (I normally grab from a few frames in to avoid initial black/blank frames) ... see https://gist.github.com/Bertg/507804 for an example (the third script - video_thumbnail - is what you'll want to start with