# Generating a thumbnail from standard html5 video player?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, thumbnails

I have a standard html5 video player but there is no thumbnail displayed before the video plays (similar to how YouTube works). Is it possible to get a thumbnail? I was thinking of taking the first frame of the video and displaying that but I'm not sure if that can be done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

with the HTML5 `<video>` element you have the `poster` attribute which will let you do this, eg:

```
<video id="myVideo" controls poster="http://{uri}/images/myVideoPoster.png">...
```

but you will still need to generate the poster image. For that you could use something like `ffmpeg` to extract a frame - either the very first, or one for a couple of seconds in, to display eg:

```
ffmpeg -i {input file} -ss 00:02:30 -vframes 1 -s 128x72 {image}
```

-ss is the timestamp for the frame, and the -s parameter is the size of the output image

Depending on your platform, you could do this automatically using something like paperclip for Ruby (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341723/using-paperclip-with-video-upload-to-get-poster/21368348#21368348)

Comment: We can't run ffmpeg on Google apps. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if you can reach out to http://ffmpegasaservice.com/ from  your particular Google Apps config (AppEngine or Cloud?)

Comment: It appears that Google App Engine doesn't like it... I honestly cannot think of a solution.

Comment: silly question, but how/where are you storing the videos? One option would be to upload them and then run ffmpeg on your PC (or scripted via a service) to create the thumbnail and store it. It's hacky but if AppEngine is where you need to be (love the free tier!) then it might be the easiest solution

Comment: The videos are being stored on Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: if the option of running ffmpeg externally (eg on a PC) doesn't work, then the other option would be to spin up and tear down small cloud compute/EC2/Azure instance to grab the video, run ffmpeg and then post the resulting frame(s) back to Storage. Also upvote this https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7010 for a possible GAE hosted solution ...

Comment: @Offbeatmammal: where should we specify the destination path for generated image to be saved and what is {image} in which you have specifed

Comment: Anywhere you like... Just need to be able to access it from the web when you post it

Comment: Actually i am  using ffmpeg to convert my video formats in my local machine and then uploading to web here i am specifying format like  
-i sourceFileLocation  -qscale 0 -ar 44100 destFileLocation

i.e here iam specifying destFileLocation (Where to save converted video file) in the same way if i generate image file where should i specify destination location